# Remove "_100" or "_150" or "_num" alone from the end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I remove _100 from the end of the string, It should be removed only at the end of the string.
For e.g 
marks_old_100 should be "marks_old".
marks_100 should be "marks".

```js
function numInString(strs) {
  let newStr = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    let noNumRegex = /\d/
    let isAlphRegex = /[a-zA-Z]$/
    if (isAlphRegex.test(strs[i])) {
      newStr += strs[i]
    }
  }
  return newStr
}

console.log(numInString('marks_100'))
```

Comment: Any efforts so far ? please post the code you have written ?

Comment: This does vary slightly from the duplicate in that this question asks about removing the underscore as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following snippet:

```js
const s = 'marks_old_100';

// remove any number
console.log(s.replace(/_[0-9]+$/, ''));

// remove three digit number
console.log(s.replace(/_[0-9]{3}$/, ''));

// remove _100, _150, _num
console.log(s.replace(/_(100|150|num)$/, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
string.replace(/_\d+$/g, "")
```

It makes use of regexes, and the `$` matches the end of the string. `.replace` then replaces it with an empty string, *returning* the string without `\d+` on the end. `\d` matches any digits, and `+` means to match more one or more.

Alternatively, if you want to match the end of a word, try:

```js
string.replace(/_\d+\b/g, "")
```

which utilises `\b`, to match the end of a word.

Comment: This works fine, but I also want to avoid _xxx or _xxxx from the string.

Comment: @AlaguSelvan I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean, you want to remove anything after the underscore?

Comment: @AlaguSelvan if so, try `string.replace(/_[a-zA-Z\d]{3,4}$/g, "")`

Comment: I want to remove all chars that the end that ends with "_number".

Comment: @AlaguSelvan see now.

Comment: @ Geza Kerecsenyi It worked fine thanks.